# Reference request: generalized Lefschetz-Hopf fixed point theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$. A basic (and very important) theorem is that we have equality 
$$
  \# X(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}) = \sum_{i=0}^{2\dim X} (1)^i \operatorname{tr}({\Phi^\ast}^n,\operatorname{H}_{et}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_\ell))
$$
where $\ell$ is a prime distinct from $p$ and $\Phi:X\to X$ is the Frobenius. One takes as motivation the Lefschetz fixed point theorem in algebraic topology, which says that if $X$ is compact and $f:X\to X$ is a continuous map with finitely many non-degenerate fixed points, then 
$$
\# X^f = \sum (-1)^i \operatorname{tr}(f^\ast,\operatorname{H}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}))
$$

My understanding is that both theorems admit generalizations. Let $f:X\to X$ be an arbitrary regular map on a smooth projective variety over some field $k$. Let $\ell$ be a prime invertible in $k$. Then we have 
$$
  (\Gamma_f \cdot \Delta_X) = \sum (-1)^i \operatorname{tr}(f^\ast,\operatorname{H}_{et}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_\ell))
$$ 
and the same should hold for maps on compact topological spaces (maybe compact oriented manifolds). My question is:

> Is there a good reference for the generalized Lefschetz-Hopf fixed point theorem (in algebraic topology)?

Even better would be a "sheafy" reference.

(A good reference for this in algebraic geometry is SGA 5, III.4.)

Comment: The way you phrase it, seems like the first statement you make about etale cohomology corresponds to the first statement (the motivation part) of singular cohomology. Is there a reason why? It seems more natural that your statement in etale cohomology corresponds to the topological satement instead, since $f$ is no longer confined to Frobenius.

Comment: I'm not very picky about precisely what statements in etale cohomology correspond with some given theorem in algebraic topology. I'm much more interested in a modern reference for the theorem in topology.